# Para que sirven las clases struct en c#

Tags: c#

Para que sirven las clases struct en c# ya que he visto lo siguiente :

Una clase `inPFile`

```
 public class inPFile
 {
     public int P_Id { get; set; }
     public string P_Name { get; set; }
     public string P_Nick { get; set; }
 }
```

Y otra clase `outPFile`

```
public  class outPFile
{
    public struct PFileNodes
    {
        public int P_Id { get; set; }
        public string P_Name{ get; set; }
        public string P_Nick { get; set; }           
    }
}
```

Esto mejora el rendimiento?, o que mejora? es buena practica?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 6):

Los struct no son clases, son estructuras. Una estructura es una agrupación logica y tiene varias propiedades parecidas a una clase, pero no tiene las mismas caracteristicas.

La idea general de un struct es tener autocontenido alguna tipo logico de dato. Los ejemplos mas comunes serian un punto (que ya viene como un struct en el framework) o un color. O Hasta podrias contener toda la información de un archivo adentro de una estructura.

Tene en cuenta que un struct es muy eficiente en muchos casos, ya que la traza en memoria es mucho mas chica. Asi mismo, un struct esta definida como un tipo por valor, por lo tanto cualquier copia de la misma crea una nueva structura.

Hay varias reglas para crear structs:

- No pueden contener constructores sin parametros.
- Sus propiedades no pueden ser inicializadas por defecto. (salvo
  algunos casos)
- Se instancian sin usar un new.
- No pueden heredar de otra ni implementar una interfaz
- Otras reglas mas (ver la documentación [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs))

Pueden contener entre otras cosas:

- constructores
- constantes
- campos
- metodos
- eventos
- Y mas (ver [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct))

Un ejemplo podria ser:

```
Public struct Archivo
{
    public int Tamaño;
    public string Nombre;
    public date FechaCreacion;
    public bool SoloLectura;
}
```

Tene en cuenta, que nada mejor que chequear la documentación siempre.

Y a tu pregunta de si es una buena practica, es depende como lo uses. Que sea una buena practica, depende de que lo uses en el lugar y momento correcto. 
Muchas veces, una clase es desperdiciar mucho espacio. Sobre todo, si la clase no tiene nada mas que campos.

Comment: "Se instancian sin usar un new." también se pueden instanciar con new. Es mas, se deben instanciar con new si necesitas un constructor específico.

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que tu pregunta se resume en "*¿cuándo debo escoger una estructura y cuando una clase?"*

En general es una decisión subjetiva, pero según microsoft se debe escoger una estructura cuando se cumplan las siguientes condiciones:

> Considere la posibilidad de definir una estructura en lugar de una clase si las instancias del tipo son pequeñas y normalmente de corta duración o suelen estar incrustadas en otros objetos.
>
> Evitar definir un struct a menos que el tipo tenga todas las características siguientes:
>
> - Representa lógicamente un valor único, de forma similar a los tipos primitivos (int, double, etcetera.).
> - Tiene un tamaño de instancia inferior a 16 bytes.
> - Es inmutable.
> - No tendrá que realizar la conversión boxing con frecuencia.
>
> <sub>[Fuente](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct)</sub>

Pero incluso Microsoft "viola" estas reglas si es necesario. Con lo que como digo, es una decisión personal elegir una u otra, la principal diferencia para mi es que es que una estructura es un tipo por valor y una clase es un tipo por referencia, y es lo que puede decantarte por una u otra. No hay una norma estricta sobre cuando usar una u otra...

Answer (score 0):

*Hola Gbianchi*

Las estructuras adentro de la programación sirven para almacenar variables adentro de un código y después poder utilizarlas con otras variables. 
Por ejemplo, imagínate que tienes una caja con herramientas que tienes que usar para arreglar un auto.

Tenemos 3 herramientas, un martillo, varios clavos y una silla.
Entonces, para poder arreglar el auto, necesitaremos una silla para poder utilizar el martillo para luego insertar los clavos adentro del auto.
El martillo tiene que ser el adecuado, de plástico o de metal. Si es de metal,
introducirá 20 clavos pero si es de plástico, introducirá 10 clavos.

```
    public struct Auto
    {
        public string Martillo;
        public int clavos;
        public bool silla;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Introducimos las variables

        Auto auto;

        auto.Martillo = "Martillo de metal"; // Tenemos un martillo de plastico.
        auto.clavos = 10; // Tenemos 10 clavos.
        auto.silla = true; // Disponemos de una silla.

        if (auto.silla)
        {
            if (auto.Martillo == "Martillo de metal")
            {
                auto.clavos *= 2;
                Console.WriteLine("Se han podido insertar {0} clavos con exito.", auto.clavos);
            }

            else if (auto.Martillo == "Martillo de plastico")
                Console.WriteLine("Se ha podido insertar los {0} clavos con exito.", auto.clavos);

            else
                Console.WriteLine("Usted tiene una silla pero no dispone del martillo adecuado");
        }

        else
            Console.WriteLine("Usted no dispone de una silla");
    }
```

Si te diste cuenta, todas las variables(el martillo, la silla y los clavos) las almacena una estructura llamada "Auto".

En conclusión, las estructuras vendrían a ser bloques de codigo que almacenan variables para luego poder ser utlizadas

Comment: Te recomendaria que volvieras a leer el [tour], no me queda claro si entendiste como funciona el sitio (en las respuestas no se puede nombrar a nadie, ya que no llegan notificaciones. Ademas me estas contestando a mi, cuando la pregunta no es mia). Ademas, te recomendaria que vieras [answer]. No me queda claro el sentido de esta respuesta (que agrega a las que ya hay). Fijate esas cosas para evitar que te sigan dando puntos negativos. Si tenes alguna duda, sobre esta respuesta, deja un comentario y usa @gbianchi asi me llega un aviso.

Answer (score -3):

Una estructura seria muy parecido a una clase **estática** que no necesita crear una instancia, o utilizar new, siempre y cuando sean solo campos.

Sin embargo si se requiere algo mas complejo, como **métodos** por ejemplo una clase es la opción, ya sea estática o no.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con una clase estatica. La instancia se crea exactamente como creas una instancia de una clase, con new, solo que al ser un tipo de datos por valor y no por referencia, tienen valores por default.